# virtualenv in PowerShell?

Tags: python, powershell, virtualenv

There seems to be a problem when [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) is used in PowerShell.

When I try to activate my environment in PowerShell like...

```
env/scripts/activate
```

.. nothing happens. (the shell prompt should have changed as well as the PATH env. variable .)

I guess the problem is that PowerShell spawns a new cmd. process just for running the activate.bat thus rendering the changes `activate.bat` does to the shell dead after it completes.

Do you have any workarounds for the issue? (I'm sticking with `cmd.exe` for now)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

My original answer is now outdated. Now, just use `activate.ps1` (rather than `activate.bat`) to activate from a Powershell environment.

---

*Original answer:*

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100413093317/http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/NothingSolvesEverythingPowerShellAndOtherTechnologies.aspx)'s a post that contains a Powershell script that allows you to run batch files that persistently modify their environment variables. The script propagates any environment variable changes back to the calling PowerShell environment.

Comment: This works, but one can't add the prompt argument. There would have to be an activate.ps1 that could call Write-Host before the prompt is set.

Comment: This answer is no longer valid as virtualenv supports powershell out of the box as pointed out in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365081/virtualenv-in-powershell/10030999#10030999

Comment: the link goes to 404 page

Comment: Link is missing

Comment: Try: `./Activate.ps1`

Comment: `venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1` is what I have to use in Powershell

Answer (score 163):

**[The latest version of virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) supports PowerShell out-of-the-box**.

Just make sure you run:

```
Scripts\activate.ps1
```

instead of

```
Scripts\activate
```

The latter will execute `activate.bat`, which doesn't work on PowerShell.

Comment: You may need to run `set-executionpolicy RemoteSigned` to allow scripts to run (mine was set to `Restricted` before) [docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176961.aspx)

Comment: and simply type `deactivate` to undo

Comment: Is there a way to change the color of the prompt using this approach?

Comment: null_pointer: The color of the powershell is most easily changed by right-clicking on the navigation bar -> Properties -> Colors.

Comment: This actually doesn't work for me even though it appears to work.  Open two powershell cli windows.  do pip freeze in both.  in one of them create a virtualenv and activate.  do pip freeze in both.  see that the packages did not install into the virtualenv.

Comment: Note that the script creates an in memory function for deactivation. It's named `deactivate`.

Comment: I had to write: `./Activate.ps1` it didn't work otherwise for me.

Comment: If you don't have admin privileges, you may need to run `set-executionpolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser` instead of the command provided by Alex L

Answer (score 47):

Run the this command:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force
```

followed by:

```
./env/Scripts/activate.ps1
```

That's all

Comment: If you are using `python -m venv venv` to build your virtual environment, then the name of script would be `Activate.ps1`.

Answer (score 24):

A quick work-around would be to invoke cmd and then run your activate.bat from within the cmd session.  For example:

```
PS C:\my_cool_env\Scripts> cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\my_cool_env\Scripts>activate.bat
(my_cool_env) C:\my_cool_env\Scripts>
```

Answer (score 17):

Inside of the Scripts directory of your virtual environments folder there are several activation scripts that can be used depending on where you are executing the command.  If you are trying to activate your virtual env from the Windows PowerShell, try using the following command:

`. .\env\Scripts\activate.ps1`

In the event you receive an error about the activation script being disabled on your system, you will first need to invoke an execution policy change on your system.  This will need to be done as the administrator.

**To do this:**

1) Right click on the PowerShell application and select Run as Administrator

2) Run the following command: `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`

3) Rerun the activation command: `. .\env\Scripts\activate.ps1`

Answer (score 6):

try this:
`. .\env\Scripts\activate.ps1`
watch dots and spaces

Answer (score 4):

This error happens due to a security measure which won't let scripts be executed on your system without you having approved of it. You can do so by opening up a powershell with administrative rights (search for powershell in the main menu and select Run as administrator from the context menu) and entering:

*set-executionpolicy remotesigned*

for more:
http://www.faqforge.com/windows/windows-powershell-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system/

Answer (score 4):

**Windows users**

> In Powershell:

1. **Run Powershell as an administrator**
2. copy and paste this command: `set-executionpolicy remotesigned`
3. Agree to the message.

Finally, Run

```
your_virtualenv_name\Scripts\activate.ps1
```

Instead of

```
your_virtualenv_name\Scripts\activate.bat
```

> In CMD
>   Just run:

```
your_virtualenv_name\Scripts\activate.bat
```

Answer (score 4):

env\Scripts\Activate.ps1 cannot be loaded because script execution is disabled on this system.

Set-Execution Policy can be used to allow the current user to run scripts as shown below.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser
```

After that run...

```
env/Scripts/Activate.ps1
```

Answer (score 3):

On Windows PowerShell, I have to type from the venv/Scripts folder :

```
. ./activate
```

Answer (score 2):

firstly, make sure you are allowed to run Scripts. If not activate it.
Now open the powershell
pip install virtualenv (if virtualenv is not installed in your system)
python -m virtualenv myenv (here "myenv" is the name of your environment)

#activating the virtual environment you created:
myenv/Scripts/Activate.ps1

#deactivating the virtual environment:
deactivate

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem too! and finally found out what should we do in windows...

ok, follow these steps:

1)Type powershell in search bar of windows then right click on it and select Run as Administrator

(if you have problem in that check [this](https://www.top-password.com/blog/5-ways-to-run-powershell-as-administrator-in-windows-10/))

2) Run the following command in powershell: Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

3) Rerun the activation command:`.\\env\Scripts\activate.ps1`

(just run the exact command! be careful about name of your environment.)

and that's it!:)

Answer (score 1):

Just 2 more suggestions:

Because it is always problematic to weaken a security policy i would advice to do it the minimal way for Powershell:
invoke Powershell not as administrator but as the user who wants to use the virtualenv functions. Type
"set-executionpolicy -executionpolicy unrestricted -scope currentuser".
This way the policy is changed only for one user and not for the whole machine.

Secondly I would advice to download from github the sources
"regisf/virtualenvwrapper-powershell". After download unpack the zip-file to a local directory and run the file "Install.ps1" inside. This will expand the Powershell profile permanently on your machine and hence enable the use of all "virtalenvwrapper-win" commands including "workon". After that you will not notice any difference in the behaviour of Powershell and the Commandshell concerning virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Power shell is consider powerful and "turbo-charged" than the normal command  prompt shell.
In an instance you are using visual studio code (VScode), running power shell to launch Python Virtual Environment may throw error especially on windows 10, as shown below.

> \Activate : File C:\users\titus\django1\Scripts\Activate.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.
> For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
> At line:1 char:1

To solve this, you can do the following:

1. Go to windows Setting
2. Open update & Security
3. Select "For Developers"
4. Enable the developers mode
5. accept all the terms

Thank you
all the best

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this quick little script to handle my activation and startup of a dev server.

```
$ep = Get-ExecutionPolicy

if ($ep -eq 'RemoteSigned') {

    $root = "C:\Users\ALeven\OneDrive\!code_projects\!django_projects\"

    $test = Read-Host -Prompt 'Would you like to activate the python environment? y/n'
    if ($test -eq 'y') {

        $activatestr = ($root + "\work_venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1")
        & $activatestr

    }

    $test = Read-Host -Prompt 'Would you like to run the python server? y/n'

    if ($test -eq 'y') {

        $whichserver = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the name of the project.'
        $path = ($root + $whichserver)
        $runserverstr = ($path + "\manage.py")
        python.exe $runserverstr runserver

    }

} else {

    Write-host "Execution Policy does not allow this script to run properly"
    Write-host "If you have the proper permissions,"
    Write-Host "Please close powershell,"
    Write-host "then right click the powershell icon and run as administrator"
    Write-host "Once in the powershell environment, execute the following:"
    Write-host "Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force"

}
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little script to activate it.

```
# Don't forget to change execution policies
# Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope CurrentUser
# More info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7

if (Test-Path env:VIRTUAL_ENV) {
    deactivate  
}

$env = .\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1

# use $env to set variables, for instance $env:FLASK_APP = "main.py"
```

Remember to save file with PowerShell extension `.ps1`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still struggling to get things going, Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you cd into the location of activate.ps1, running `activate.ps1` could return "The term 'activate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet".

In order to run activate.ps1 from the current location try:

```
.\activate.ps1
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem in any shell of PowerShell and finally I just typed *activate* command with *.* prefixes.[image: you can see my final way in yellow characters]