# Can a Batch script know if it's called from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Is there any way a batch script can know if it's called from PowerShell (without extra parameters feeded)?

Need something like..

```
if (%THIS_BATCH_CALLED_FROM_POWERSHELL%)
    ... warn the user or drop back to powershell to execute the proper instructions...
```

Question related with [this question - virtualenv-in-powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365081/virtualenv-in-powershell/1365119#1365119).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue.  Batch files are not directly executed from PowerShell.  When you execute a batch file within PowerShell, a new instance of cmd.exe is spawned to do the actual execution of the batch file.

Comment: I think he wants to find a way to alter environment variables in the Powershell environment.

Comment: @Keith Hill: Exactly. And I'm in search for a way to know, from within the batch script, if it is called from PS.

Comment: @JasonTrue: that too, but first at least we need to detect if we're in PS environment or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a tool like "tlist.exe /t" or [this one](http://www.scheibli.com/projects/getpids/index.html) to display the PIDs of the current process and all parent processes.  You could check each one of those PIDs to see if any correspond to PowerShell.exe.

Comment: That's an ugly way but at least does the job. Thank you Keith.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a default warning in the script and pass it a flag that tells it not to show the warning. When you call it from power shell pass it that flag.

Comment: The intention is to do this without a flag. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my Powershell environment (a PS 2.0 CTP), I seem to have an environment variable PSMODULEPATH which is not set by the normal command line environment, but still exists when Powershell has a child CMD.exe shell.

I think you might be able to "reliably enough" check for the existence of PSMODULEPATH in your batch script.

Comment: Are you sure? %PSMODULEPATH% seems to be a global env. setting and thus exists on cmd.exe shell too on my machine.

Comment: Not sure, as I only have my machine to check against, but when I run "CMD.exe" from Explorer, it doesn't exist. When I run Powershell, it does exist. When I run cmd.exe from Powershell, the environment is copied into the new cmd.exe and it exists there.

Comment: %PSMODULEPATH% is a global env variable for me on Win7.