# installing flask in Python on Heroku

Tags: python, facebook, heroku, flask, virtualenv

I'm trying to follow this [guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python).
I made `virtualenv` and installed `flask` in it:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Flask in     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Werkzeug>=0.7 in   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Flask)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Jinja2>=2.4 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Flask)
```

After `pip freeze > requirements.txt` the file contains only:

```
argparse==1.2.1
distribute==0.6.28
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

And there is no Flask package. I'm trying to run simple example and got:

```
ImportError: No module named flask
```

How to install the package properly?

Comment: Did the first output result from `pip install Flask`?

Comment: @jsalonen here is the first output: http://pastebin.com/1fWBDjYa

Comment: You need to activate virtualenv for sudo as well. However the whole point in virtualenv is that you don't need to use sudo. So just omit `sudo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `pip freeze > reuirements.txt` inside your virtualenv. Thus, make sure that your virtualenv was activated correctly. As the Heroku documentation is mostly written from Linux point of view, this may be a little tricky especially on Windows (see [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365081/virtualenv-in-powershell)):

- Windows command-prompt activation is done using `venv\Scripts\activate.bat`
- If you are using Windows PowerShell, you need to run `venv\Scripts\activate.ps1` instead.

Note that you need to activate virtualenv for `sudo` as well. Example:

```
sudo bash
source venv/bin/activate
pip install Flask
```

However one of the points in virtualenv is that you don't need sudo. Thus, you could simply omit using sudo and simply just run:

```
source venv/bin/activate
pip install Flask
```

Comment: hm, app is running but requirements.txt after updating still  the same

Comment: Can you find Flask directory under your virtualenv? I mean do you have `flask` folder under `venv/lib/site-packages`?

Comment: in venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages i have distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg  easy-install.pth  pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg  setuptools.pth, no flask

Comment: It means you didn't run `pip install Flask` inside your virtualenv, which is what you need to do! You probably have Flask installed globally under Python's shared site-packages, which is the reason why your app works, but pip freeze doesn't, since it only freezes the dependencies under the virtualenv.