# Can't Activate Virtualenv on Powershell

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I'm trying to learn Django.
To start, I needed to install Python, Django, and Virtualenv. These are all installed with no errors. But now that I want to start a project and run virtualenv, I can't activate it in the powershell.

I used this command to make a virtualenv:

```
python -m virtualenv venv
```

Now the tutorial says that I have to activate virtualenv like this:

```
. \scripts\activate
```

but it gives me this error:

```
    . : The term '\scripts\activate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:3
+ . \scripts\activate
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\scripts\activate:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What should I do?

I have tried `scripts\activate.ps1` but it still is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works perfectly with cmd, and not Powershell.

Comment: I actually found a way in which I could activate it in PowerShell as well:
env/scripts//activate

Answer (score 2):

You should to use `scripts\activate.ps1` instead of `scripts\activate`. Find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365081/virtualenv-in-powershell)

Comment: `activate.ps1 : The term 'activate.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ activate.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (activate.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

Comment: It works completely fine on Cmd but it doesn't work on Powershell. I tried it as an admin too. Still not working