# How to deactivate virtualenv in PowerShell

Tags: python, windows, powershell, virtualenv

So I am aware of [virtualenv in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365081/virtualenv-in-powershell) question, specificly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1365119/2018369), stating that all you need to activate is to execute

```
venv/Scripts/activate.ps1
```

Of course it is required to set appropriate Execution Policy etc.

But my question is: How to **disable** virtualenv activated inside Power Shell?

I tried:

```
venv/Scripts/deactivate.ps1
```

and

```
venv/Scripts/activate.ps1 deactivate
```

but first one fails because deactivate.ps1 does not exists and second one does not change anything.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just a moment after creating this question I've realized that answer is much simpler that I expected. All I need is to type

```
deactivate
```

inside virtualenv.

Comment: > ... It is better to ask a stupid question first, so you save a lot of time for everyone. JBP

Comment: this is deprecated if youre using conda as of april 2023. it is now: conda deactivate