# Why won't it allow me to activate my venv?

Tags: powershell, command-prompt

I've researched a few things about opening a venv. I've come to realize I need the PowerShell to allow scripts and so I started this session with:

```
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
```

Then I went ahead and tried the following, but it is not going through.

P

```
S C:\Windows\system32\xxxxx> venv/bin/activate
venv/bin/activate : The term 'venv/bin/activate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ venv/bin/activate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (venv/bin/activate:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Windows\system32\xxxxx> source venv/bin/activate
source : The term 'source' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ source venv/bin/activate
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (source:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Any suggestions as how to move forward?

Comment: What do you think about using WSL?

Comment: Use `activate.ps1` instead of just `activate` in powershell: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10030999/7411885

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I am getting the same issue as before when I use `venv/bin/activate.ps1`

Answer (score 0):

I had been following a tutorial and they used `venv/bin/activate` when it should be `venv/Scripts/activate`