# How to activate a venv in VSC?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a Python script open in VSC. I have a venv (Python 3.10.0) selected as the Kernel. In terminal I have the following line:

```
PS C:\Users\person123\Desktop\Project\venv>
```

I think my venv is not activated. Am I correct and how to activate it? The instruction tricks I've seen (for example this `venv\Scripts\activate`) don't activate this venv. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: If youn have active the Python extension by microsoft, simply select the interpreter using the CTRL+shift+p shortcut (open the command palette) and selecting the "python: select interpreter" command. You should see your path already there, otherwise there is a select button so you can indicate your full path

Comment: select the interpreter in the venv, close all terminals, start a launch config and VSC will open a terminal and activate the venv

Comment: @rioV8 what does "start a launch config" mean?

Comment: have you read the VSC doc pages about debugging

Comment: What Andrea says.   Funny thing that may not be apparent - it wasnt to me -  is that picking the Python executable, *in its location in the venv*, is more or less equivalent to running activate script.

Comment: Selecting an interpreter in vscode, it will be automatically activated.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting an interpreter by shortcuts **"Ctrl+Shift+P"** and type **"Python: Select Interpreter"** in vscode, environment will be automatically activated when you run the python script.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using powershell. To activate your venv, you should run the `activate.ps1` script:

```
.\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1
```

And to check if it is properly activated, check the path of your python executable:

```
(Get-Command python).Path
```

It should point to your python venv.

Comment: ```.\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1``` did not activate it :(

Comment: Have you run also the command suggested by the first comment of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10030999/13339621

Comment: since you are in the venv folder already try `.\Scripts\activate.ps1`

Comment: @matleg yes I tried it but I didn't even understand what was the purpose of seeing the path, and I'm not sure if this ```.\Scripts\python.exe``` is the path. I don't see any "select button" either

Comment: Thanks @JonSG but that didn't activate it

Comment: The point is that if the printed path is the one to your venv, in your case:
C:\Users\person123\Desktop\Project\venv\Scripts\python.exe , it means your venv is activated.